Why is the $\alpha$-divergence unique in positive measure space $\mathcal{M}$?
In this article https://bsi-ni.brain.riken.jp/database/file/298/303.pdf (S. Amari 2009), it is said that a $f$-divergence (eq. 17) which can be written by a decomposable Bregman divergence (eq. 53) with expression $r(m)$ must satisfy
$$mf\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)=r(m)r^*(n)$$
How do you derive this ?

You should try to make your post self-contained. Also, I cannot parse your first sentence.
